# Rotating the standard Cartesian coordinate system to make the z-axis parallel to the given vector

Tags: math, vector, rotational-matrices

There is a vector `P = (Px, Py, Pz)` in standard Cartesian coordinate system. Now I want rotate the standard Cartesian coordinate system in such a way that z-axis become parallel to the vector `P`.

What I have done is the following:

1. First I normalised the vector P and calculated the projection of normalised vector P (P_proj)on the xz-plane.
2. I have calculate the angle (θ) between the z-axis and P_proj.
3. I have rotated the Cartesian coordinate system around the y axis with θ degree. z-axis is parallel to P_proj and named it z1-axis.
4. I have calculated the angle between the vector `P_new` (updated after the rotation of the system) and z1-axis (ϕ) and rotate the Cartesian coordinate system again around the x1-axis with an angle. Now this z2-axis after second rotation will be parallel to the vector `P`.

Comment: I suppose you want your coordinate system to remain Cartesian. But even then, you will have to decide on an additional constraint. Making the Z-axis parallel to your vector P leeves the X- and Y-axes free to rotate 360° in the plane orthogonal to P.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cross product X. If Qhat is any unit vector that isn't equal or close to equal to Phat, preferably such that |Phat.Qhat| < 0.5 say, then you can use

```
z = Phat

x = (Phat X Qhat) / |Phat X Qhat|

y = (Qhat X x) / |Qhat X x|
```